# SQL Server 2008 sdf linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

Please who to create a linked server to local `.sdf` file??

Note: I can't find the provider of SQL Server CE with the gui method, so I did this

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   
     @server=N'Post1', 
     @srvproduct=N'',
     @provider=N'Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5', 
     @datasrc=N'c:\articles.sdf';
```

It works and I can browse tables of `articles.sdf` file, but if I do a select request the system crash and print this error message :

> Msg 0, Level 11, Condition 0, Line 0
>   A severe error occurred on the current command. The possible results are to be ignored.
>
> Msg 0, Level 20, Condition 0, Line 0
>   A severe error occurred on the current command. The possible results are to be ignored.

1000 thanks

Comment: Since SQL Server CE really isn't a *server* - creating a "linked server" is kinda impossible .....

Comment: so why it is possible to do this with access file ?????